# Manually trigger Angular to reevaluate the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to trigger Angular to reevaluate the DOM?
I am looking for a way to manually make Angular reevaluate the entire DOM, or better yet, a specific ng-controller DOM-Node.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Its not clear what you asking . please provide more details and explain the use case.

Answer (score 1):

if you're outside of an digest loop you can enter it by calling $rootScope.$apply() or $scope.$apply()